# Get src parameters from iframe through javascript

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I have a following iframe with different parameters such as time,query.
I want to extract the parameters from this iframe through javascript so that I can replace the values of the selected parameters.
How can I do that?

```
<iframe src="http://localhost:5601/#/dashboard/New-Dashboard?
embed&_g=(refreshInterval:(display:Off,pause:!f,section:0,value:0)
,time:(from:now-6M,mode:quick,to:now))&_a=(filters:!(),panels:!
((col:1,id:env,row:1,size_x:4,size_y:3,type:visualization),
(col:5,id:env-2,row:1,size_x:4,size_y:3,type:visualization),
(col:9,id:env-3,row:1,size_x:4,size_y:3,type:visualization)),
query:(query_string:(analyze_wildcard:!t,query:'*')),title:'New%20Dashboard')
" height="600" width="800" id="myframe"></iframe>
```

Comment: You say `parameters` - are you talking about GET parameters, the values from the brackets included to a GET parameter or both?

Comment: Here, I would like to extract **time:(from:now-6M)**, so that I can replace now-6M with a new value passed.. @firian

Answer (score 0):

I see this working in two steps.  1) Grab your `src` string, and 2) parse out the parameter.

1. With jQuery, this can be done simply with `var frame_src = $('#myframe').attr('src');`
2. Next, I recommend using regular expressions to pull out your parameters. The easiest way to do this is to design your parameter names and values such that they fit a specific, easy to match pattern.

For example, you could set it up such that parameter name will be led by either a "?" or a "&", and followed by a ":". They key value pair will end with either another "&" or the end of the string ("$").  The pattern would look something like this:

```
var attr_name = "The attribute you're looking for";
var kvpair_pattern = new RegExp("[\?|&]" + attr_name + ":\w+[&|$]");
```

And you would extract the data with the `exec()` method.

```
var mydata = kvpair_pattern.exec(frame_src)[0];
```

Keep in mind, you will have the leading "?" or "&" with this method. I don't know of a work-around other than stripping it off as an afterthought since JavaScript doesn't support look-behinds.